# Microsoft Excel - Creating several separate graphs at once

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Excel 2016. Suppose I have one column with about 1000 values corresponding to a horizontal axis, while I have 25 separate columns for vertical axes. I am looking for a way to automatically create 25 separate graphs, with the same layout and format, at once, without manually specifying the data series for each individual graph.

I know I can create one graph with all of the data, so maybe there's a way to break that into 25 separate graphs?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @altair176,, are U looking to use entire data set for all 25 Graphs or is there any possibility to make group of data while break it ?

Comment: I would do this in VBA, have it run through each column and create a graph that way.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your X values are in column 1 of a range, and your Y values are in columns 2 through 26. I also assume the first row of each column contains text that will be used for the series name.

To make definition of the data range easier, I assume it starts in cell A1. I did not include any formatting, or even chart type, since it wasn't specified. But you can get a lot of that by recording a macro while making a chart manually, then copying pieces of the recorded macro into this one.

```
Sub MakeOneChartForEachColumn()
  Dim DataRange As Range
  Set DataRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
  '' change definition of data range as needed

  Dim XValues As Range
  Set XValues = DataRange.Columns(1).Offset(1).Resize(DataRange.Rows.Count - 1)

  Dim iChart As Long
  For iChart = 1 To DataRange.Columns.Count - 1
    Dim MyChart As Chart
    Set MyChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart
    With MyChart.Parent
      .Left = 15 * iChart
      .Top = 15 * iChart
    End With

    MyChart.ChartArea.ClearContents

    With MyChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
      Dim YValues As Range
      Set YValues = XValues.Offset(0, iChart)
      .Values = YValues
      .XValues = XValues
      Dim NameCell As Range
      Set NameCell = DataRange.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, iChart)
      .Name = "=" & NameCell.Address(, , , True)
    End With

    '' formatting etc. goes here
  Next
End Sub
```